# Is it better to use one or multiple requestAnimationFrame for multiple canvas objects?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have created a small canvas program that draws cubes and has them reflect off walls. My question is, for an object oriented canvas program such as this, is it better that each new cube has its own animationFrame or should this be handled by a single, 'global' animationFrame? Here's a fiddle [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6KVxd/) demonstrating the program in action.

Below is an example of the code that each cube object has.

```
animation: function (animation_type, value_x, value_y) {
   data.animation = requestAnimationFrame(this.animation.bind(this, animation_type, value_x, value_y));
   draw.reflect(value_x, value_y);
}
```

This method can be called from a new object instance by using `YOUR-VARIABLE-NAME.method.animation('x', x-integer-value, y-integer-value)`.

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: One. requestAnimationFrame has high overhead.

Comment: Sound advice. How would one go about moving these objects independently? Would I need to recursively call these functions to animate the cube objects?

Comment: Yup. Loop thru the objects updating them.

Comment: Thanks @bjb568. You've been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Code to animate simultaneously on multiple elements, sharing the same requestAnimationFrame, duration and fps.

13/09/2016 - Added easing formulas from gizma.com; Each param can get a individual easing formula.

24/09/2016 - Added onCompleteFunction, removed part to find out the original value. Now the function must receive the initial value. The array push was giving issues when used to dynamically create a menu (loop)

Array strucutre on the code.
Any improvements are most welcome.

Hope it helps.

```
    var objects = []; 
    var object = [];
    var obj1 = [];
    var obj2 = [];
    var obj3 = [];
    var obj4 = []

//obj = element, param, unit, initialValue, targetValue, easing formula //
obj1.push(document.getElementById('obj1'), ['left','px', 0, 420, 1], ['top','px', 0 ,120, 6], ['width', '%', 80, 90, 4]);
obj2.push(document.getElementById('obj2'), ['top','px', 0, 420, 7], ['width','%', 80, 90, 2], ['height', 'px', 20,  900, 9]);
obj3.push(document.getElementById('obj3'), ['height','px', 0, 220, 9], ['top','px', 0, -80, 4]);
obj4.push(document.getElementById('obj4'), ['top','px', 20, 620, 1], ['width','px', 120, 380, 4]);

    objects.push(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4);
/* Object array structure:
[ [ 0 - object, [0 - param, 1- paramUnit, 2- originalValue, 3 - targetValue, 4 - easeFormula ] ], [... [...] [...] ] ]
*/

    startAnimation(objects, 2, 60); //objectsArray, seconds, fps

 function startAnimation(objects, seconds, fps, onCompleteFunction) {
    var now;
    var fps = fps;
    var duration = seconds * 1000; //miliseconds
    var startTime = Date.now();
    var previous = startTime;

    var interval = 1000/fps;
    var stop = false;
    var delta;

    var frameCounter = 0;
    var elapsed = 0;
    var info = document.createElement('p');
    document.getElementById('info').appendChild(info);  

    animate(objects, now, startTime, previous, fps, interval, stop, delta, duration, elapsed, frameCounter, onCompleteFunction, info);
} 
function animate(objects, now, startTime, previous, fps, interval, stop, delta, duration, elapsed, frameCounter, onCompleteFunction, info) 
{
        if (stop) {
            return;         
        }  
        window.requestAnimationFrame( function() { animate(objects, now, startTime, previous, fps, interval, stop, delta, duration, elapsed, frameCounter, onCompleteFunction, info); }
        );      
        now = Date.now();
        delta = now - previous;
        if (delta > interval) {        
            /* Just `previous = now` is not enough.
            Lets say we set fps at 10 which means
            each frame must take 100ms
            Now frame executes in 16ms (60fps) so
            the loop iterates 7 times (16*7 = 112ms) until
            delta > interval === true
            Eventually this lowers down the FPS as
            112*10 = 1120ms (NOT 1000ms).
            So we have to get rid of that extra 12ms
            by subtracting delta (112) % interval (100).
            Hope that makes sense.  */      
            previous = now - Math.round(delta % interval); //<-- unconsistency on end frames
            elapsed = (previous - startTime)/1000;  // return value in seconds 
            frameCounter++;

            animateObjectsArray(objects, elapsed, duration);
            runInfo(elapsed, previous, startTime, frameCounter, info);

        }
        if (now - startTime >= duration) {
            stop = true;                
            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                for(var j = 1; j < objects[i].length; j++) {
                    objects[i][0].style[objects[i][j][0]] = String(objects[i][j][3]) + objects[i][j][1];
                }
            }
            onCompleteFunction();
        }
}
function animateObjectsArray(objects, elapsed, duration) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 1; j < objects[i].length; j++) {
            objects[i][j][5] = Math.round(easeArray[ objects[i][j][4] ]( elapsed , objects[i][j][2], (objects[i][j][3] - objects[i][j][2]), duration/1000) );   
            objects[i][0].style[ objects[i][j][0] ] = String(objects[i][j][5]) + objects[i][j][1];  
        }               
    }

}
function runInfo(elapsed, previous, startTime, frameCounter, info) {     
    info.innerHTML = frameCounter + 'f / ' + parseInt(elapsed) + 's = ' + parseInt(frameCounter/elapsed) + 'fps<br />'; 
}
// t = time (elapsed), b = initialValue, c = change(FinalValue - initialValue), duration)
var easeArray = [
    //0 - simple linear tweening - no easing, no acceleration
    function linearTween(t, b, c, d) {
        return c*t/d + b;
    },
    //1 - quadratic easing in - accelerating from zero velocity
    function easeInQuad(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        return c*t*t + b;
    },
    //2 - quadratic easing out - decelerating to zero velocity
    function easeOutQuad(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        return -c * t*(t-2) + b;
    },
    //3 - quadratic easing in/out - acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    function easeInOutQuad(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        t--;
        return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    },
    //4 - cubic easing in - accelerating from zero velocity
    function easeInCubic(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        return c*t*t*t + b;
    },
    //5 - cubic easing out - decelerating to zero velocity
    function easeOutCubic(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        t--;
        return c*(t*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
    //6 - cubic easing in/out - acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    function easeInOutCubic(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
        t -= 2;
        return c/2*(t*t*t + 2) + b;
    },
    //7 - quartic easing in - accelerating from zero velocity
    function easeInQuart(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        return c*t*t*t*t + b;
    },
    //8 - quartic easing out - decelerating to zero velocity
    function easeOutQuart(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        t--;
        return -c * (t*t*t*t - 1) + b;
    },
    //9 - quartic easing in/out - acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    function easeInOutQuart(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
        t -= 2;
        return -c/2 * (t*t*t*t - 2) + b;
    },
    //10 - quintic easing in - accelerating from zero velocity
    function easeInQuint(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        return c*t*t*t*t*t + b;
    },
    //11 - quintic easing out - decelerating to zero velocity
    function easeOutQuint(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        t--;
        return c*(t*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
    //12 - quintic easing in/out - acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    function easeInOutQuint(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
        t -= 2;
        return c/2*(t*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
    },
    //13 - sinusoidal easing in - accelerating from zero velocity
    function easeInSine(t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * Math.cos(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + c + b;
    },
    //14 - sinusoidal easing out - decelerating to zero velocity
    function easeOutSine(t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
    },
    //15 - sinusoidal easing in/out - accelerating until halfway, then decelerating
    function easeInOutSine(t, b, c, d) {
        return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
    },
    //16 - exponential easing in - accelerating from zero velocity
    function easeInExpo(t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.pow( 2, 10 * (t/d - 1) ) + b;
    },
    //17 - exponential easing out - decelerating to zero velocity
    function easeOutExpo(t, b, c, d) {
        return c * ( -Math.pow( 2, -10 * t/d ) + 1 ) + b;
    },
    //18 - exponential easing in/out - accelerating until halfway, then decelerating
    function easeInOutExpo(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow( 2, 10 * (t - 1) ) + b;
        t--;
        return c/2 * ( -Math.pow( 2, -10 * t) + 2 ) + b;
    },
    //19 - circular easing in - accelerating from zero velocity
    function easeInCirc(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
    },
    //20 - circular easing out - decelerating to zero velocity
    function easeOutCirc(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        t--;
        return c * Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) + b;
    },
    //21 - circular easing in/out - acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    function easeInOutCirc(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return -c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
        t -= 2;
        return c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) + 1) + b;
    }
]
```

Keep in mind to declare the initial param on the html element:

```
<div class="info" id="info" onClick="" style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 100px; bottom: 0px">
</div>

<div class="obj1" id="obj1" onClick="" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left: 160px; top: 240px; background-color: #00aa00">
</div>

<div class="obj2" id="obj2" onClick="" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left: 60px; top: 110px; background-color: #00ccdd">
</div>

<div class="obj3" id="obj3" onClick="" style="position: absolute; width: 10px; height: 160px; left: 20px; top: 170px; background-color: #aacc22">
</div>

<div class="obj4" id="obj4" onClick="" style="position: absolute; width: 160px; height: 120px; left: 160px; top: 210px; background-color: #bbcc00">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rrafw/4vxqLs3q/

Comment: After reading through this answer, it doesn't provide a direct, clear and distinguished answer to the original question.